# Mismatch row numbers in tables MySQL-R created with same code

Tags: mysql, r, row, mismatch

I am using R (Rstudio) to import tables from MySQL (workbench). I am creating a table (cit_EP) through a query based on another table (citations_patent_families) I have already created in MySQL. The issue is that even though I use the same exact query in both R and MySQL the resulting dataframe/table are slightly different. The number of observations in R is systematically higher than the number of rows in the table created in MySQL. Someone has any idea on how this can be explained and solved?

MySQL code:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cecilia.cit_EP; 
CREATE TABLE cecilia.cit_EP AS
SELECT *
FROM citations_patent_families
WHERE earliest_filing_year >= 1978
  AND earliest_filing_year <= 2020
  AND appln_auth = 'EP'
```

The resulting table has 78.121.862 rows

R code:

```r
cit_EP = dbGetQuery(con, "
  SELECT *
  FROM citations_patent_families
  WHERE earliest_filing_year >= 1978
    AND earliest_filing_year <= 2020
    AND appln_auth = 'EP'")
```

The resulting dataframe has 80.317.700 obs

Comment: Incidentally, you can replace `earliest_filing_year >= 1978 AND earliest_filing_year <= 2020` with `earliest_filing_year between 1978 and 2020`.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the underlying table `citations_patent_families` changes between the two calls. There is nothing in the queries that would indicate any difference in returned value.

Comment: Make sure that `con` variable is connected to the same database used in MySQL sample.